# Guess timezone name for custom date

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I know that I can get browser timezone name: `moment.tz.guess()`

How can I guess timezone for custom date? e.g. `moment("2020-12-30T14:17:40+11:00").tz.guess()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  There are 9 different location-based zones that use +11:00 year round, and 5 more that use it for daylight saving time.

You might be able to eliminate a few if the date and time put it into a time zone where daylight time is *not* in effect and the standard time doesn't match, but from there, the best you could do would be to pick one at random.

See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Moment-timezone can guess the *browser's* time zone because it can query the offset for *multiple* different timestamps, algorithmically reducing the possibilities.  Even then, there are often several that could match, and thus the most likely one is picked (based on population statistics).  In the end, it's still a guess.