# Getting timezone from offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to trigger time based events on my server which runs in UTC time.
In my UI, I am accepting 2 parameters

1. The local time the trigger that needs to be run
2. The timezone offset

I preferred to not show timezone names because it delays the page rendering and I believe its unneeded.

I checked the moment library and I don't see how to get the timezone name from timezone offset. The API `moment.tz.names()` returns all timezones.

IS there an API which returns, say 
`moment.tz.name('330') = 'Asia/Kolkata'`
Also, if there is a solution, would DST problem be addressed

Comment: Did the information that you need is in 'new Date()' (for me it's give: Thu Feb 23 2017 16:54:19 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)). If yes, I can make you a REGEX to extract them.

Comment: example.. you would give a custom time, say 17h and 00 minutes, to run an event. Additionally, you would send +1 as offeset.. The server is in UTC timezone. It has to run event at 17:00:00 GMT +0100

Comment: So you just need the offset ? the +1

Comment: No, there is no API that returns timezone name from offset, I fear that is not possible to get this kind of output from offset, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34535479/4131048).

Comment: The client should send a date in UTC it will be easier. So if the user select 17:00 (+1 GMT) it send 18:00

Comment: Kornflexx, VincenzoC .. Belive a simple JS date + offset calulation would suffice for me. although i am losing DST. I wonder if same timeoffest which can have different timezone follow differrent DST begin/end dates

Comment: Original Poster:  Please remember to accept an answer if you feel it is correct and/or meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

So there will always/often be multiple names for any particular offset so there is no `moment.tz.name('offset') = 'Country/Zone'` api that I know of.

You can however get an array of all names based on an an offset with a simple filter function

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const getZoneFromOffset = offsetString => moment.tz.names().filter(tz => moment.tz(tz).format('Z') === offsetString)

console.log(getZoneFromOffset("+05:30"))
// [ 'Asia/Calcutta', 'Asia/Colombo', 'Asia/Kolkata' ]
```

In the example above I used `"+05:30"` for the offset value which doesn't 100% match you use case of 330 but it demonstrates how to work the problem. You can also get an array of all the timezone names with their offsets like with a simple map on moment.tz.names()

```js
const getZoneObjects = () =>  moment.tz.names().map(zone => ({ zone, offset: moment.tz(zone).format('Z') }))

/*
[
  { zone: 'Africa/Abidjan', offset: '+00:00' },
  { zone: 'Africa/Accra', offset: '+00:00' },
  { zone: 'Africa/Addis_Ababa', offset: '+03:00' },
  ...
*/
```

The examples above use `Z` as the timezone format but if `"+5:30"` doesn't match your needs you can look at https://devhints.io/moment to see the other formats you can use for example `ZZ` which would be `"+0530"` in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

When working with fixed offsets, you do not need to use Moment-Timezone.  All of that functionality is provided with Moment itself, with either the `parseZone` or `utcOffset` functions.

There's an example [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) that matches your scenario well.

> ...
>
> One use of this feature is if you want to construct a moment with a specific time zone offset using only numeric input values:
>
> ```
> moment([2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]).utcOffset(-5, true) // Equivalent to "2016-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
> ```